# How to animate slider captions if position is fixed?

Tags: jquery, gsap, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) slider, and I've created a fixed position captions for it. I don't want them to move with the slide as usual, so I lifted captions out of the slide. I got it to work, but I'm having trouble animating titles with [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/). I know how GSAP works, but I don't know how to animate titles in this particular situation.

For example: if the slide changes then the previous slide titles fade out + slide up, and the next slide titles fade in + slide up. I hope you understand what I mean.

Maybe someone here can help me with this: https://jsfiddle.net/x0sukfd6/

Thank you.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: false,
    speed: 1200,
    grabCursor: true,

    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true,
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    on: {
      slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
          // Slide captions
          var swiper = this;
          var slideTitle = $(swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex]).attr("data-title");
          var slideSubtitle = $(swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex]).attr("data-subtitle");
          $(".slide-captions").html(function() {
            return "<h2 class='current-title'>" + slideTitle + "</h2>" + "<h4 class='current-subtitle'>" + slideSubtitle + "</h4>";
          });
      }
    }
});

// Slide captions on load
var sizes1 = $(mySwiper.slides[mySwiper.activeIndex]).attr("data-title");
    var sizes2 = $(mySwiper.slides[mySwiper.activeIndex]).attr("data-subtitle");
    $(".slide-captions").html(function() {
    return "<h2 class='current-title'>" + sizes1 + "</h2>" + "<h4 class='current-subtitle'>" + sizes2 + "</h4>";
});
```

Comment: [Same post on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24300-how-to-animate-slider-captions-if-position-is-fixed/) for reference.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, it did not help me. As I mentioned, I understand how GSAP works, but it doesn't help me specifically with this situation.